# "The group looked at tissue from people who had any of five diagnoses" - why isn't there "the" before "five diagnoses"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

From a [news report](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2160697-first-glimpse-of-how-genes-may-cause-mental-health-problems/):

> The group looked at tissue from people who had any of five diagnoses: autism-like conditions, schizophrenia, bipolar disorder, depression and alcoholism.

Why isn't there a definite article before "five diagnoses"? They are listed, so it's a definite word. I would have used **the**:

> The group looked at tissue from people who had any of **the** five diagnoses: autism-like conditions, schizophrenia, bipolar disorder, depression and alcoholism.'

Comment: With "They are listed, so it's a definite word" it is not clear to me what you mean. The word **five** there specifies only the number of items in the list. *You have to go to bed early tonight for three reasons: ....*  You wouldn't want to say "for **the** three reasons", right, even if we list the reasons. One could say **these five diagnoses** upon first mention.  **the five diagnoses** would suggest they are commonly found in that grouping, like "the Seven Deadly Sins" or "The Three Musketeers".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - thank you, it's clearer to me now. I will never have the natural feeling for articles. (0:

Comment: Your feeling for them is quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group looked at tissue from people who had

any of these five diagnoses: ...

any of five diagnoses ...

any of the five diagnoses

**these five diagnoses** = focus your attention, listener, on this list of five diagnoses I am about to enumerate

**five diagnoses**  =  five diagnoses were involved...

**the five diagnoses** =  listener, I'm speaking of the five diagnoses with which you are familiar or have already heard about (or which I intend to make my topic)